# How to run WP-CLI using bash script in linux

Tags: linux, wordpress, bash, git-bash, wp-cli

I'm having issue to run bash script setting up WP-CLI by it's own. Keep on getting wp no command found error. Please help.

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -O https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wp-cli/builds/gh-pages/phar/wp-cli.phar
chmod +x wp-cli.phar
mv wp-cli.phar /usr/local/bin/wp
exec bash
wp --info
wp plugin install taxonomy-terms-order --path=/var/www
wp plugin activate taxonomy-terms-order --path=/var/www
```

It's only running till exec bash line. after that its not installing any plugin. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not hesitate to make small experiments to understand the problem:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

echo "Test 1"
exec bash
echo "Test 2"
$ echo $$
6506
$ ./test.sh 
Test 1
$ echo $$
6548
```

`exec bash` is opening a new blocking process.

So, I think you can remove this line from your script.

If `/usr/local/bin` is not in your `PATH`, you can use the complete path of `/usr/local/bin/wp` instead of `wp` :

```
/usr/local/bin/wp --info
/usr/local/bin/wp plugin install taxonomy-terms-order --path=/var/www
/usr/local/bin/wp plugin activate taxonomy-terms-order --path=/var/www
```

Or you can add this path to the `PATH`:

```
export PATH="${PATH}:/usr/local/bin/wp"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That worked. I didn't think of that full path. Anyways thanks again.